# Subscript out of Range Error Excel Copy/Paste

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below code to try to copy and paste B4 from sheet 10 to sheet 6 and then in column b of sheet 6 enter a time stamp.

However, I am getting the `subscript out of range` error on the line of code where the * is.

```
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Dim copySheet As Worksheet
 Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

 Set copySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet10Name)   ****
 Set pasteSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet6Name)

 copySheet.Range("B4").Copy
 pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
 Range("B" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select
 ActiveCell.Value = Now()
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Now apparently I am not getting the now() to insert the time stamp in column b of sheet6.

Correct end result

```
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Dim copySheet As Worksheet
 Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

 Set copySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet10.Name)
 Set pasteSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet6.Name)

 copySheet.Range("B4").Copy
 pasteSheet.Cells(pasteSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
 pasteSheet.Cells(pasteSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = Now()
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: What is the value of `Sheet10Name`?

Comment: `Sheets(Sheet10Name)` did you mean `Sheets(10)`?

Comment: @findwindow -- why would he mean that instead of what he said?

Comment: @roryap `try and copy and paste b4 form sheet 10 to sheet 6`

Comment: @caleb kleveter if you're going to edit, please correct the typo XD

Comment: @CalebKleveter `form sheet 10 to sheet 6` Edit: I would consider editing `B4` as well.

Comment: Rude to edit someone else? Edit: I guess not exactly polite to critique another's edit XD

Comment: @findwindow -- What does this "XD" mean that you keep typing?

Comment: @roryap emoticon ^_^;

Comment: Have you tried to "record macro" while doing it manually and checked the difference afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's the way you're using (perhaps misusing) the `Sheets()` part.  Try this:

```
Sub t()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Dim copySheet As Worksheet
 Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

 Set copySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet10.Name)
 Set pasteSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet6.Name)

 copySheet.Range("B4").Copy
 pasteSheet.Cells(pasteSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
 pasteSheet.Range("B" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select
 ActiveCell.Value = Now()
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Also note that I explicitly gave the sheet in your `Rows.Count` and `Range("B" & Activecell...)` parts, which should help too.  Without that, you'd likely get some errors as you switch worksheets.

Comment: (SheetX.Name) fixed that issue, but now it wont insert the now() timestamp. I may make another question for this unless you have some advice on that?

also Range("B" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select worked but when you stated the pastSheet in front of it it errored out.

Comment: @DougCoats - I have a feeling that it's due to the `ActiveCell` part, not the `now()` part.  What cell do you want to put the `Now()` info in? Let's instead use something like `Cells(1,1).Value = Now()`, but we need to determine which cell you want the active cell to be.

Comment: i guess i am still a new. I thought "pasteSheet.Range("B" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select" was making the active row of column b the active cell? or does it need to be pasteSheet.Range("B" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value= Now()   ?

Comment: @DougCoats - Check out [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) on how to avoid using `.Select`, which is best practice for VBA.  It looks like you're starting to see how to do that...and you're correct (and I just overlooked that part) that `.select` makes it active.  So yes, try using `pasteSheet.Range("B" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value= Now() `.  However, I'd like to remove all `.Select` -  so it looks like the cell you want with `Now()` is going to be the last row of your pasted range, plus one row, correct?

Comment: Correct. Though this did work, when I try activating this multiple times the timestamp doesnt go into the active row, and only goes in b3 (weird) and replaces the timestamp each time. I have a feeling I need to redo that whole line to include an offset reasoning

Comment: @DougCoats - Yes! If you can add some logic that determines the cell, do that.  It's tricky when you use `.Select` and `ActiveCell` (`Active` anything really).  I'll tweak the code in a minute.